# Time & Space complexity for the two input array

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, space-complexity

What is the time & space complexity of this function? This function takes two inputs and both are in same size.
Please ignore the functionality of this function() because it might not sense, so this is just a resemblance of the original loops.

As it takes two inputs, time complexity or space complexity should be denoted as T(n, m). The first nested for loop gives us O(n^2), and similarly the second takes O(m^2).
Since there are two nested for loops and both of them with same size, only one of them is considered for time complexity. So is it either T(n, m) = O(n^2) or T(n, m) = O(m^2) ??

What would be the space complexity for this function considering the two input array fo same size?

```
function (arr1[], arr2[])
{

for (i = 0 to arr1.length) {
    for (j = 0 to arr1.length - i -1) {
        if (arr1[j] < arr1[j + 1]) {
            arr1[j] = arr2[j]
            arr2[j] = arr1[i]
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0 to arr2.length) {
    for (j = 0 to arr2.length - i -1) {
        if (arr2[j] < arr2[j + 1]) {
            arr2[j] = arr1[j]
            arr1[j] = arr2[i]
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You can also denote the complexity as e.g. O(n²+m²). About space complexity: That should in fact be O(1) since no _additional_ space is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since in-place changes happen for both arr1 and arr2, is the space complexity O(1)? If the arr2 is not an input array but auxiliary array, will it be the same time-complexity and space-complexity?